# Java awt SystemTray MouseListener Not working

Tags: java, notifications, awt

Showing notification part is always working but registered mouse events do **not(never) get fired**. Here is my code; Since it is a console application, all methods are static and i dunno whether it has impact.

```
public  class NotificationUtils {

public static void showNotification(String Message,final String url) throws AWTException {

    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    //If the icon is a file
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
    //Alternative (if the icon is on the classpath):
    //Image image = Toolkit.getToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image,"Tray Demo");
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Eventte");
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(url).toURI());
            }catch (URISyntaxException|IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Eventte");}
        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
    });
    //Let the system resizes the image if needed
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    //Set tooltip text for the tray icon
    trayIcon.setToolTip("New Notification");
    tray.add(trayIcon);
    trayIcon.displayMessage("Atanmamış Bildirim Var", Message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
}
}
```

**How this method is called;**

```
   NotificationUtils.showNotification(ticket.getSubject(), address);
```

This is my edit, it is not opening still. Why mouse events are not fired. I check it with System.out

```
private static SystemTray tray;
private static TrayIcon trayIcon;

public static void showNotification(String Message,final String url) throws AWTException {

    if(tray == null) {
        tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        //If the icon is a file
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
        //Alternative (if the icon is on the classpath):
        //Image image = Toolkit.getToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");
        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Eventte");
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(url).toURI());
                } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        //Let the system resizes the image if needed
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        //Set tooltip text for the tray icon
        trayIcon.setToolTip("New Notification");
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    }
    trayIcon.displayMessage("Atanmamış Bildirim Var", Message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
}
```

Comment: Your basic code works fine, I'd suggest the issue is somewhere else.  I would make sure that you're only adding the `TrayIcon` once to the `SystemTray`, otherwise you might end up with some additional strange behaviour

Comment: @MadProgrammer the issue might be in adding many MouseListeners? Maybe he is calling the same function many times.

Comment: This method can be called numerously before previous SystemTray is being showed thus it can cause weird behaviour you think?

Comment: Try to define the MouseListener outside of the function itself

Comment: @MertSerimer I have no idea.  It's just a bad idea to try and use `SystemTray` to send messages to the user like this.  Typically, you'd have one `TrayIcon` through which you'd communicate

Comment: @MertSerimer When I run your code and send two messages, I get two icons, which isn't really helpful to the user, as they would typically only expect on icon for the application. The good news though is, each icon had it's own `MouseListener` and responded with the correct `url` value

Comment: @MadProgrammer so the MouseListener worked?

Comment: @AlexCuadrón Still works fine

Comment: I tried this but it is not still working. Can it be related to me not being local admin? I can open browsers as me with my mouse. Please see Edit

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146537